# iOS App unable to send json file to flask API

Tags: swift, api, flask

I have an app which collects data and send it to my flask server. I am able to establish connection successfully but I am unable to save the data into my local machine. See below my code:

iOS side:

```
@IBAction func detectSteps(sender: UIButton) {

    print(data_dict)
    guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data_dict, options:[.prettyPrinted]) else{ return }
    print("My jsonData")
    //below two lines check if the json was converted properly or not
    if let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print(JSONString)
    }
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://10.105.86.98:8000/dataCollect") else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return}
    print(url)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Context-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{ _, _, _ in })
    task.resume()
}
```

Flask Side:

```
data = jsonify(request.get_json(force = True))

with open(data, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as train_file:
    dict_train = json.load(train_file)
    json.dump(data, train_file)

df_json = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_train)

df_json.to_csv('Data_Collection\test_file1.csv')
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port = 8000, debug = True)

Comment: "Context-Type" looks like a typo, try with "Content-Type" instead.

Comment: tried with "Content-Type", still an error